# How does Malkav's blood affect dhampirs?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I've been reading some effects of Malkav's blood and I was wondering if there are some official rules for a Dhampir that drinks its blood. To clarify, I'm talking about the creatures born of one thin-blood and a human, not the Dhampyr of the Kue-Jin. Are there rules covering this situation that I've missed somewhere?

If there are no such rules, would these house rules be consistent/balanced?

- When a Dhampir takes one point of the blood of Malkav, it is considered a ghoul with a 3rd generation domitor. As the rules for this don't exist, I'm thinking of giving the Dhampir a maximum rank for his disciplines of 5, as if he had a 4th generation domitor, but he does not need to drink blood regularly, just one time per year.
- The Dhampir gets one free point of one discipline of his decision (only physic or mental disciplines).
- For (20 - Humanity) nights, the Dhampir will suffer the Curse of Caine like a vampire, suffering the effects of the sun, the blood-loss every night, the fire weakness and the effects of Rötschreck. After that, the Dhampir will recover from the Curse of Caine. *But* if the Dhampir has a humanity of 3 or less, he will instead permanently become a full-fledged vampire.

Comment: Do you mean the blood of the actual Malkavian Antedeluvian?  Can I ask the source of material specifically referring to Malkav's blood?

Comment: Yes, I've found it in a book called Fountains of Bright Crimson.

Comment: And yes, the Malkavian Antediluvian itself

Comment: I've written "Antedeluvian" somewhat like the spanish translation (in spanish is "Antediluviano"), sorry...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I'd like to say that bringing 3rd generation vampire (or even his blood) to your chronicle (and even worse - giving it to your player) is a **BAD IDEA**. It is comparable to giving your trigger-happy player a nuclear weapon, ring of wish with unlimited charges or Scroll of Summoning Cthulhu - Antediluvians are godlike beings and should not be brought as a footnote in character creation "oh btw, I've drank from Malkav himself". Methuselah - sure, but Antediluvian? Please no.

Now back to the original question. Since I do not believe that there would be rules for drinking Antediluvian blood (for reasons mentioned above), let's look at your homemade rules for dhampir-turned ghoul (with ancient domitor).

There is only one official rule: **Do not mix templates** and if you really, really have to, give it gigantic penalties (check [Abomination](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Abomination) for example) or simply say that "now X became Y".

What you are trying to do is create a ghoul who doesn't have to drink his master's blood often...  So as a general rule I'd say that [dhampir that drinks other vampire's blood is simply a ghoul](http://www.fataladdiction.com/dhampir.html).

*When a Dhampir takes one point of the blood of Malkav, it is considered a ghoul with a 3rd generation domitor.*

- Vitae is addictive. It's like with the anti-meth ads - "even once is once too much". Now drinking antediluvian blood would be hundred times more addictive... Doing it once a year wouldn't do - its not a matter of HAVING to drink but WANTING to drink.
- To use disciplines Ghoul burns the vitae of his domitor. Dhampir uses his own blood, dhampir-ghoul could use both... but for balance's sake I'd say that you first burn your domitor's blood.
- Also please note that [ghouls tend to get their domitor's flaw](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44264/do-ghouls-get-their-masters-clan-flaw). In  case of drinking such potent blood it would happen much more quickly.

*The Dhampir gets one free point of one discipline of his decision (only physic or mental disciplines).*

- Ancient vampire's blood would be strong enough to give a free discipline point (but only once)  and indeed 4th generation dormitor gives his ghouls access to 5th level disciplines - nothing wrong here, just please read my first paragraph.

Comment: I'ts a really good answer. And no, I don't want a player being involved with Antediluvians, it was just for a NPC. If I give the power of an Antediluvian to a player it could be crazy, and I don't want gods.